# Is it necessary to get product id for every individual paid content from ituneconnect?>

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, product

I am working on a `IOS` project where I have to integrate in app purchase. While integrate in app purchase should I register all of the content I want to sell in `ituneconnect` to get product id?

Say, I have 100 content to sell or paid content. should I Register and get product id for all 100 content?

if yes then what should I do if I add more paid content later?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, [reference](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf) from Apple:

> After you have decided what type of items you’re going to provide for
>   In-App Purchase, proceed by writing clear item descriptions, picking
>   appropriate pricing, and designing an In- App Purchase store to
>   showcase your items.

I can recommend you to read the reference.

Comment: What should i do if i want to add more paid content dynamically?

Comment: You might want to consider an alternative method like purchasing credits to the cash in for items.